# To put space before method signature or not?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I would like to know what the overall recommendation is for whitespace between a method's name and its parameters.

That is, the general preference between the following two lines:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {} // (We'll ignore the question of spaces between the `String` and `[]` .)
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

I recently have begun to feel like the former is the better one, especially considering that everything else in a method declaration (e.g. the `throws Exception(s)` section) is also space-separated.

Comment: I personally like extra spacing if it improves readability.

Comment: Forgive me if this style guide is not in any way official (I'm not that experienced with Java common knowledge), but http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#682

Comment: more space more happy

Comment: Followers of the The Great God Cthulhu demand the ritual sacrifice to the Great Old Ones of all those using spaces after the method name...  Other religions may have different rules... Check with your local religious leader (or the mystical tome known as the "Coding Standard")

Comment: I suggest you don't spend more than about five seconds of your time and your employer's money worrying about trivia like this.

Comment: @EJP, I totally agree on the fact that it's not a huge deal when compared to some other things, but it's the sort of stylistic thing that I think would be important to be confident in if your code will be read by your coworkers or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @chris mentioned in the comments, the [Official Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#682) specifically states:

> Note that a blank space should not be used between a method name and its opening parenthesis. This helps to distinguish keywords from method calls.

As you questionably considered in your question, methods are different on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

**2018 update**: since almost all IDEs allow easy invocation/declaration lookup, the main gains of switching the convention here are moot; after 3 years, I've switched back to "no space after method name" rule just because *most style guides in most languages use it*... making an exception to existing code styles is IMVHO viable when the gains outweigh the "WTF factor" of the change; in this case, with up-to-date tooling, there are no actual gains, so I'd personally recomend *against* the alternative proposed below.

---

I beg to differ with the interpretation of [1999's unmaintained White Space Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#682). It only says that the space shouldn't be used to help distinguish *keywords from method calls*. Thus, there ain't no official rules as to whether use the space in contexts where method call can't appear (and thus where no such help is needed) - as such, the rule obviously *does* apply to invocative context (where calls can appear and where it helps) and *doesn't* apply to declarative context (where calls can't appear and where it would serve no purpose). Even more - because the conventions state that the whitespace use should *help in distinguishing the usage context*, using space on declaration actually keeps with the spirit of the rule - it actually allows you to distinguish method invocation from method declaration, even when using simple text search (just search for the method name followed by space).

After switching to it, distinguishing invocations from the declaration got easier. It also highlighted the fact that the parentheses after the name ain't the invocative ones - and that their syntax is different from the call syntax (i.e. type declarations are needed before variable names etc.), as you noticed already.

**tl;dr** you can use

```
void method () { } // declaration
void method2 () { // declaration
    method(); // invocation
}
```

to be able to quickly do searches on declarations/invocations only *and* to satisfy the convention at the same time.

<sub>Note that all the official Java code, as well as most of the code styles in the wild, *doesn't* use the space in the declarations.</sub>